# array.sort(), possible without declaring 0 value?

Tags: typescript

In the case of array sorting, would it be possible to use

```
    array.sort((item1: any, item2: any) => {
        return item1.value < item2.value ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

instead of

```
    array.sort((item1: any, item2: any) => {
        if item1.value < item2.value ? -1;
        if item1.value > item2.value ? 1;
        return 0;
    });
```

My goal is to use as little code as possible. Instead of specifically returning 0 like in my latter code, wouldn't the first patch of code automatically resolve the "0"-cases? If not, why not?

It's an array of { [key: string]: string } and I want to sort alphabetically.

Comment: You're about to make your code incorrect to (maybe) remove a few bytes from your bundle. Don't. Strive for correctness, and let the minifier and the gzip compression reduce the size of the bundle. If your comparator tells that A < B **and** that B < A, it's broken.

Comment: Also, if it's an array of `{ [key: string]: string }`, then use **that** as a type, rater than using any.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do that? You *can* do that, but the function *should* be aware of both items being equal to work correctly. If you are looking for a one liner here you go:

```
array.sort((item1: any, item2: any) => {
    return item1.value === item2.value ? 0 : (item1.value < item2.value ? -1 : 1);
});
```

Or even:

```
array.sort((a: any, b: any) => ({a.value === b.value ? 0 : (a.value < b.value ? -1 : 1)}));
```

For numbers only you can simply subtract one number from another:

```
array.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.value - b.value);
```

Comment: " You can do that, but the function should be aware of both items being equal to work correctly." Can you show an example where sort would not work correctly with `item1.value < item2.value ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: It can be shortened for an array of numbers only.

Comment: I just tried it with an array of objects and it works.

Comment: I assume `a.value` is a scalar number value, not an object.